# Ternary Operator in C# with 3 conditions

Tags: c#

I have scenario in which I am having 3 conditions i.e

[image: Conditions table]

Can i write this conditions with the help of one ternary operator in C#?. For 2 conditions i know we can write like this :

```
string.Compare(SaveAsOption, "Comparison document", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0 ? .pdf : .docx;
```

Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: In the image you posted, there are two different results for a same condition (or I didn't understand your table)

Comment: I guess if you really want, you can stack them up as much as you want. `condition ? true : (condition2 ? true : false)`

Comment: Please, do not post code as images and provide minimal reproducible sample

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski the image isn't code

Comment: The ternary operator is probably not your best option here. It might help to know what result you really want, that code won't compile.

Comment: why not switch?

Comment: @user12675659 please, show us the rules for all 3 extensions

Comment: Forget that you want to answer that question in C#. Answer it in English first. *What extension should the file have if the user requested to save it as a Comparison document?* Note that *"Either .pdf or .wdf"* is not a valid answer.

Comment: @Rafalon please read this meta question [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski This image isn't code, like Rafalon has mentioned. It's a table.

Comment: Hi users,  I am having 3 conditions as : Once when "SaveAsOption" is "Comparison document" then Type should be ".pdf" , then for the next time when "SaveAsOption" is "Comparison document" then Type should be ".wdf" and for the last time when "SaveAsOption" is "Word document with Track changes" then Type should be ".docx" . I am providing Value of SaveAsOption from one excel as that is optionvalue present in my AUT. So, i just wanted to check what would be the best way to handle this 3 conditions? Hoping now the question is clear. Pardon me for any confusions.

Comment: We asked you several times now: what is the difference between *"Comparison document"* and *"Comparison document"*?

Comment: Why not a simple list of allowed type and a contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can i write this conditions with the help of one ternary operator in C#?*

The answer to this is **no**.

---

As per your comment:

> When I am selecting `SaveAsOption` as `"Comparison document"` then I would be getting 2 options to select one would be `.pdf` an other one would be `.wdf`

Then you actually want to use `SaveAsOption` as a *filter* (as it isn't itself sufficient to determine which option to chose) and **need a second user interaction** when there are more than 1 resulting item in your filtered list

```
List<FileOption> availableOptions = new List<FileOption>
{
    new FileOption{Type = ".pdf", SaveAsOption = "Comparison document"},
    new FileOption{Type = ".wdf", SaveAsOption = "Comparison document"},
    new FileOption{Type = ".docx", SaveAsOption = "Word document with Track Changes"},
};

string strInput = "Comparison document";

var result = availableOptions
    // Filter the list
    .Where(o => o.SaveAsOption == strInput)
    .Select(o => o.Type)
    .ToList();

if(result.Count > 1)
    Console.WriteLine("Please choose an option: {0}", string.Join(" or ", result));
else if(result.Count == 1)
    Console.WriteLine("You chose {0}", result[0]);
else
    Console.WriteLine("There is no option for your selection");
```

This displays:

- with `strInput = "Comparison document"`:

  > Please choose an option: .pdf or .wdf
- with `strInput = "Word document with Track Changes"`:

  > You chose .docx
- else:

  > There is no option for your selection

Comment: Thanks Rafalon ! This is the answer i was looking for :) because comparison document was a option , upon clicking on which i was getting a list of elements to select.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 conditions, in which 2 of them it is unclear what to do. If it were 3 options really, you could use ternary operator, switch, if...else if. With ternary:

```
string docType = saveAs.ToLower() == "comparison document"
      ? ".pdf" 
      : saveAs.ToLower() == "comparison document2": 
      ? ".wdf"
      : saveAs.ToLower() == "word document with track changes" 
      ? ".docx"
      : null;
```

Probably a better way would be to use a data structure like dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> options = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"comparison document", ".pdf"},
    {"comparison document2",".wdf"},
    {"word document with track changes",".docx"},
};
options.TryGetValue(saveAs.ToLower(), out string docType);
Console.WriteLine(docType);
```

Comment: Hi @Cetin . Thanks for the response ! I am having 3 conditions as : Once when "SaveAsOption" is "Comparison document" then Type should be ".pdf" , then for the next time when "SaveAsOption" is "Comparison document" then Type should be ".wdf" and for the last time when "SaveAsOption" is "Word document with Track changes" then Type should be ".docx" . I am providing Value of SaveAsOption from one excel as that is optionvalue is present in my AUT. So, i just wanted to check what would be the best way to handle this 3 conditions? Hoping now the question is clear. Pardon me for any confusions.

Comment: @user12675659 your conditions 1 and 2 are the same, how in the world do you want us to decide if you need `.pdf` or `.wdf` when `SaveAsOption` is `Comparison document`?

Comment: Hi @Rafalon , Yes that are the conditions as per my application i.e when i am selecting SaveAsOption as Comparison document then i would be getting 2 options to select one would be .pdf an other one would be .wdf . Thanks !

Comment: Then you don't need a ternary operator, you actually need to use `SaveAsOption` as a *filter* and **need a second user interaction** when there are more than 1 resulting item in your filtered list

Comment: @user12675659, then combine that 2 options into one. You have 2, not 3.

Answer (score -2):

Try this one- Nested ternary:

```
string.Compare(saveAs, "pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0 ? ".pdf" : (string.Compare(saveAs, "wdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0? ".wdf":".docx");
```

Comment: This is a naive solution, which is hard to extend and terrible to maintain. If you want to add a 4th format then this expression would be a nightmare. If you need to change the comparision then you have to change in several places.

Comment: @PeterCsala No, that's not the reason. The reason is that this does not answer the question to begin with. Then again, there can be no answer given the OP's requirements.

Comment: Question was about to manage 3 conditions and it serving the purpose. what else requirement is which my answer is not serving?